# Size type parameters in custom datatypes in Rust?

Tags: data-structures, rust, b-tree

I'm trying to implement a B-Tree class for practice in Rust, which can be instantiated at various different values of `b`. I've tried the following code:

```
struct BTreeNode<T, b> {
    vals: [Option<T>; b-1],
    children: [Option<Box<BTreeNode<T, b>>>; b],
}

struct BTree<T, b> {
    root: Option<BTreeNode<T, b>>,
}
```

but the compiler (reasonably) complains that

```
src/two_three_tree.rs:2:15: 2:16 error: unresolved name `b` [E0425]
src/two_three_tree.rs:2     vals: [Option<T>; b-1],
                                  ^
...
src/two_three_tree.rs:2:15: 2:16 error: array length constant evaluation error: non-constant path in constant expression [E0250]
src/two_three_tree.rs:2     vals: [Option<T>; b-1],
                                  ^
...
```

It looks like the B-Tree class in the standard library just uses a constant (which is a reasonable choice, since B-Trees are usually meant to take maximum advantage of caching; I'm just trying to do this in a more general way). Is this possible in the current version of Rust? If not, will it ever be possible?

(I'm imagining creating a 2-3 Tree of u32s by writing `BTree<u32, 3>`, or a 2-3-4 Tree of u32s by writing `BTree<u32, 4>`)

Comment: You are looking for *type level integers*. One such thing (which may or may not be useful) is [typenum](https://github.com/paholg/typenum). Note that earlier versions of Rust exposed the `b` parameter as a constructor parameter; the array size was then probably just a `Vec`.

Comment: I don't think it quite does what I want, but it's really cool, and I think its existence shows that arrays are unique by design, in that their type is dependent on an integer literal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using `b` as a type, then as a value, the length of the array? I'm not sure what you want that to mean.

Second, the size of an array has to be known at compile time. Since you don't know the size of the array at compile-time, you might be better off using a Vector.

Comment: As per [Rust by example](http://rustbyexample.com/primitives/array.html), "Arrays are created using brackets [], and their size, which is known at compile time, is part of their type signature [T; size]". I'm not trying to use `b` as a variable any more than I would be if I were creating an array using it (it's exactly as constant here as it is for regular arrays, since Rust does compile-time polymorphism per type instance). Any particular instance will have a size that's known at compile time; if you like, ignore that `b-1` line; you still get compile errors.

Comment: I'm imagining creating a 2-3 Tree of u32s by writing `BTree<u32, 3>`, or a 2-3-4 Tree of u32s by writing `BTree<u32, 4>`

Comment: Ah! But Rust is going to interpret `b` as a type because the angle brackets after the type indicate type parameters for a generic. If you don't know the size of the vals array at runtime, then you'll have to use something else, probably a Vector. You can dynamically choose the size of the vector in a constructor that takes an appropriate parameter.

Comment: That sounds reasonable; I was just hoping to get the same level of compile-time benefits that you get from arrays.